# VBA Excel Class Module member not populating with string

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a `Class Module` with a member not holding/populating with the required string. All other members are ok, just this one. Within the `Class Module` I have split it in two thus the portion **not** working as excpected is `ArgeementDetails` - `RebateDescription`

I can confirm when I step thru the code, the line assigning the string/text: `RebateDescription = WantedText` is correct and is passed. The line assigning to the `Class Module`: `TT.AgreementConditions RebateDescription, ValidFrom, ValidTo` I have a `break`, when I hover my cursor over `RebateDescription` there text displayed is as expected, however when I step to `Debug.Print TT.RebateDescription` the text shows "" and in the immediate window nothing is printed.

Any help to resolve this would be great.

** *Please note* **
I declare `Private TT As clsAgreementDetails` at the `Module` level as I use this across several `Subs`.

CLASS MODULE

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TAgreement
    ConditionName As String
    ConditionPricingDate As String
    ConditionRate As String
    RateUnit As String
    AgreementNo As String
    
    RebateDescription As String
    ValidFrom As String
    ValidTo As String
End Type

Private This As TAgreement

Public Property Get ConditionName() As String
  ConditionName = This.ConditionName
End Property

Public Property Get ConditionPricingDate() As String
  ConditionPricingDate = This.ConditionPricingDate
End Property

Public Property Get ConditionRate() As String
  ConditionRate = This.ConditionRate
End Property

Public Property Get RateUnit() As String
  RateUnit = This.RateUnit
End Property

Public Property Get AgreementNo() As String
  AgreementNo = This.AgreementNo
End Property

Public Sub HeaderConditions( _
    ConditionName As String, _
    ConditionPricingDate As String, _
    ConditionRate As String, _
    RateUnit As String, _
    AgreementNo As String _
)
  If Len(This.ConditionName) = 0 Then
    This.ConditionName = ConditionName
    This.ConditionPricingDate = ConditionPricingDate
    This.ConditionRate = ConditionRate
    This.RateUnit = RateUnit
    This.AgreementNo = AgreementNo
  End If
End Sub

Public Property Get RebateDescription() As String
  RebateDescription = This.RebateDescription
End Property

Public Property Get ValidFrom() As String
  ValidFrom = This.ValidFrom
End Property

Public Property Get ValidTo() As String
  ValidTo = This.ValidTo
End Property

Public Sub AgreementConditions( _
    RebateRecipeint As String, _
    ValidFrom As String, _
    ValidTo As String _
)
  If Len(This.RebateDescription) = 0 Then
    This.RebateDescription = RebateDescription
    This.ValidFrom = ValidFrom
    This.ValidTo = ValidTo
  End If
End Sub
```

MAIN SUB

```
Public Sub VF03_Process()

<snip code> 
            
            Do
            <snip code> 
                            
                            ' Create new class ready to fill with data.
                            Set TT = New clsAgreementDetails

            <snip code> 
                            
                            FillAgreementConditions
            
            <snip code>                            
            Loop

End Sub
```

SUB TO FILL CLASS MODULE

```
Private Sub FillAgreementConditions()

    Do
        Dim ColNum As Long
        ColNum = ColNum + 1
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim TestText As String
        TestText = SAPSes.findById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[" & ColNum & ",1]").Text
        Dim WantedText As String
        WantedText = SAPSes.findById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[" & ColNum & ",3]").Text
        
        ' Only update values if they are found.
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Select Case TestText
                Case "Description of agreement"
                    Dim RebateDescription As String
                    RebateDescription = WantedText
Debug.Print "Added Desc: "; RebateDescription
                Case "Valid From"
                    Dim ValidFrom As String
                    ValidFrom = WantedText
Debug.Print "Added From: "; ValidFrom
                Case "Valid to"
                    Dim ValidTo As String
                    ValidTo = WantedText
Debug.Print "Added To: "; ValidTo
                    ' Once found Valid To, last item to find, exit loop.
                    Exit Do
            End Select
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop Until ColNum = 1000
    
    TT.AgreementConditions RebateDescription, ValidFrom, ValidTo
    
' Test if results are expected
Debug.Print TT.RebateDescription
Debug.Print TT.ValidFrom
Debug.Print TT.ValidTo

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sub AgreementConditions, you are not using the RebateRecipeint parameter. You just set This.RebateDescription to itself. You want:

```
This.RebateDescription = RebateRecipeint
```

Be careful with `On Error Resume Next`. Most of your loop is under its spell. Typically, you would put `On Error Goto 0` as soon as possible after attempting to get the strings, and check for `Err.Number <> 0` just before, keeping the result in a boolean variable.

Comment: Spot on! I changed 'RebateRecipeint' to 'RebateDescription ' and missed this one... Note to self: use find/replace.. Cheers for the help!

Comment: Thanks for the tip mate. I will review my code. Cheers!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon believe it or not I use RubberDuck. And also got the tip to set up the class module from your site - https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2020/02/27/vba-classes-gateway-to-solid/